# does C has anything like python pickle for object serialisation?

Tags: python, c

I'm wondering if C has anything similar to the python pickle module that can dump some structured data on disk and then load it back later.

I know that I can write my structure byte by byte to a file on disk and then read it back later, but with this approach there's still quite some work to do. For example, if I have a single link list structure, I can traverse the list from head to tail and write each node's data on disk. When I read the list back from the on-disk file, I have to reconstruct all links
between each pair of nodes.

Please advise if there's an easier way.

Thanks heaps!

Comment: The point of C is that it _doesn't_ provide lots of high-level abstractions for you, because high-level abstractions are often imperfect and can be slow for your specific task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An emphatic NO on that one, I'm afraid. C has basic file I/O. Any structuring of data is up to you. Make up a format, dump it out, read it in.

There may be libraries which can do this, but by itself no C doesn't do this.

Answer (score 2):

The C library functions `fread(3)` and `fwrite(3)` will read and write 'elements of data', but that's pretty fanciful way of saying "the C library will do some multiplication and `pread(2)` or `pwrite(2)` calls behind the scenes to fill your array".

You *can* use them on `struct`s, but it is probably not a good idea:

- holes in the structs get written and read
- you're baking in the endianness of your integers

While you can make your own format for writing objects, you might want to see if your application could use SQLite3 for on-disk storage of objects. It's well-debugged, and if your application fits its abilities well, it might be just the ticket. (And a *lot* easier than writing all your own formatting code.)

Comment: The holes aren't that important. It's a minor increase in the serialization size, and a minor slowdown to read in or write out garbage that is never accessed, but it's not actively harmful.

Comment: @Chris, depends, if the data used to include a portion of a private key, password, or other private data that wasn't cleared before being `free()`ed, it [can lead to security problems](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/226.html).

Comment: @sarnold - It's something of a stretch to say that your security can be compromised by _fragments_ of your password taken from the cracks in the `struct` pavement.

Comment: @Chris: The holes will matter if you write on one system but read on another one with different alignment requirements.

Comment: @Chris who says structure padding / holes are small? :) A `struct sockaddr_un` is 110 bytes on my system, and a unix socket named `/tmp/foo` won't fill that by a long shot...

Comment: @sarnold - You can't possibly have a hole larger than (I suppose) `sizeof(union { intmax_t i; void *p; })` and the chances of a `struct` having a large number of large holes consecutively is extremely low. (And the chances of a password spanning very many of those 110 bytes is even lower.)

Comment: @Chris, you're right, 'hole' is only half the issue. 'un-initialized data in the structure' is more what I intended -- it covers holes, un-initialized members, as well as arrays that aren't completely filled.

Answer (score -1):

Boost has a [serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), if by "C" you mean "C or C++."

Comment: "C or C++" doesn't exist. If a question is tagged `[c]` and not `[c++]`, do not provide C++ answers.

Comment: @Chris Lutz, I note that this question is also tagged "python."  Does that mean that answers involving embedding Python in C would be acceptable?